# Confusing about the behavior of same kind of code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I am writing my first MVC3 application and I am stucked at some point. Here is what I am not clear about,

In the Taskscontroller generated Edit action looks like this:

```
// GET: /Tasks/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
Task task = db.Tasks.Find(id);
    return View(task);
}
```

and the corresponding view code is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId })
```

Here id is correctly passed to Edit action.

This is how I modified the create (Get) method to receive an id value from the view and code snippets are as follows,

```
public ActionResult Create(int i)
{
    ViewData["I"] = i;
    return View(i);
}
```

and the corresponding view code is as follows,

```
@Html.ActionLink("c", "Create", "Tasks", new { id = someId }, new { @class = somecssclass})
```

Any help is appreciated. Why in the create action id value is null?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have i parameter in action and passind id from view

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    ViewData["I"] = i;
    return View(i);
}
```

the default model binder dont find the matching recieving parameter for binding the `id` or its a typo? moreover if you want to recieve the string you should also post the string

```
@Html.ActionLink("c", "Create", "Tasks", new { id = someId.ToString() }, new { @class = somecssclass})
```

if you recieve `FormCollection` you will find the `id` there like

```
 public ActionResult Create(string i, FormCollection col)
    {
        var id = col["id"];
        ViewData["I"] = i;
        return View(i);
    }
```

Comment: 3nigma: Thank you. Yes, the    String parameter is a typo it's int in my current code. But the other suggestion of using    FormCollection to extract    id also did not work. Still id is null in the    Create action. I feel something is wrong in    @HTML.ActionLink() override? Any idea regarding this.

Comment: @KasunLak as long as `create` is the name of your action result and `tasks` your controller, the helper syntax is ok